# How can I expand the Fourier coefficient

Tags: fourier-analysis

The Fourier series is

[image]

How can I expand the Fourier coefficient $a_n$ and $b_n$ to the n order? $x\in [-Pi,Pi]$,$n \gt 0$.

Comment: I knew how to do it in math,I just what to know how can do it in mathematica.

Comment: I think you are looking for `FourierTrigSeries`

Comment: @m_goldberg I guess OP needs the general formula of the coefficient.

Comment: @xzczd. You may be right, but it's not the way I read it. I think the OP wants the expansion of the whole series he shows up to order `n`. We will only know the truth if/when the OP clarifies his question.

Answer (score 5):

Sadly there isn't a `FourierTrigCoefficient` built in *Mathematica* up to now, but you can use my [`easyFourierTrigSeries`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149469/1871) for the task.

Let me illustrate the solving process with

$$f(x)=e^{-x}$$

If we need to find the general term of $a_n$ and $b_n$ for $x\in(-1,1)$, just write

```
Clear@f
f[x_] = Exp[-x];
series = easyFourierTrigSeries[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The formula of $a_n$ and $b_n$ is already clear at this stage, simply copy them manually from the output isn't a bad idea, still, we can extract them progammatically in the following way:

```
Cases[series, a_ Cos[_] + b_ Sin[_] :> {a, b}, Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot,it's really a good idea to build easyFourierTrigSeries.

Comment: ……同学，你问题下面的评论你应该也看到了。你最好在问题里再多写几句，不然再这么下去这问题可能要被关掉了……